# How many values in one column appear in another R

Tags: r, dplyr, survey

I am working with survey data and I would like to calculate how many children each person in a household has. The dataset is the following https://github.com/aquijanoruiz/disability_benefits_EC/raw/master/rds_files/survey_data.rds

The "person" column enumerates the people living in a household. The "mother" and "father" columns indicate who the mother/father of a person is. For example, in the first houlsehold (indicated by the household_id variable 010150000201011), peron 1 and 2 are the mother and father of person 3, 4, 5, and 6 respectively.

I want to generate a variable that tells the number of children each person in a household has. For the first household it should be 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0.

I was thinking about `children %>% group_by(household_id) %>% mutate(n_chid = sum(person %in% mother, na.rm = TRUE))` but they won't work. Any ideas? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: @akrun thanks! why should we group by age? I think the age variable is irrelevant for the calculation, I just left it there so that I made some sense who is whose mother/father.

Comment: Thank you. I see the confusion. Let me clarify. The first two are the mother and father of the next four people, that's why both have 4 as their number of children. Their ages being 28 is just coincidental. For example, for person 3 (who 13 years old), the mother is person 2, and the father is person 1. I thought about `person %in% mother` because it would produce NA NA TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE, I could sum the trues and get 4. Hope this explains things more clearly.

Comment: I just downloaded it and used the command `children <-readRDS("survey_data.rds")` and it worked.

Comment: I was using `load` by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need to loop over each 'person'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
children %>% 
     group_by(household_id) %>%
     mutate(n_chid = map_dbl(person, ~ sum(mother %in% .x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

Using the OP's code with `person %in% mother` over the full group, it returns the same logical output as it includes all the rows of the group.  Instead, we need to restrict it to one observation at a time

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Yes, we had to restrict it to one observation at a time and I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Is there a way you can replicate the same results but using the apply family of functions (e.g. sapply, lapply)?

Comment: @AlonsoQuijano sure, you can change the `map_dbl` to `sapply(person, \(x) sum(mother %in% x, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @AlonsoQuijano with only base R, we may need to `split` i..e `unsplit(lapply(split(children, children$household_id), \(x) {x$n_chid <- with(x, sapply(person, \(y) sum(mother %in% y, na.rm = TRUE)); x}), children$household_id)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am less familiar with the purrr package, so I wanted to use the sapply function. I had to replace `\(x)` with `function(x)` for it to work, though. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @AlonsoQuijano the `\(x)` is from R 4.1.0 compact option for `function(x)` if you have an older R version, it may not work